# Trouble opening py file - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python

I am trying to open file in cmd command. However, this is popping up:

[image]

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\CIV4210\Research\Package for FYP>cd "data and code"
C:\Users\user\Desktop\CIV4210\Research\Package for FYP\data and code>cd PMEB.Main.py
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any recommendation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please show the image of the folder which contains this file you are trying to open?

Comment: `cd` is not purposed to open files.

Comment: Why are you trying to `cd` (change directory) into a file? That's not how you open files.

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. In this case, though, you are trying to change directory to a file. Which is never going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your filename is wrong. Do not use a `.` inside your filename. After the `.` the file extension should follow.

First check if you have python installed by just typing `python` or `python3`. If a it shows a version number python is open in an interactive shell. Close it by typing `exit()` and hitting enter. Than try to execute your `.py` file by typing `python your_filename.py`.

Comment: This answer is not necessarily wrong, but small correction here: filenames can include dots even before the file extension. One could for example create a text file named `my.text.file.with.dots.in.filename.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

The `cd` command is meant for *changing directories*, i.e. moving from one folder to another. You cannot open a file with that command. For opening a file from a command line, you need to call a different command. I cannot give you a generally working example, as this depends on the commands and programs available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use the `dir` command to ensure the file is in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized in order to open a py file need to insert python infront of the file name i.e python filename123.py

Thank you for all the comments!